# How to view type hierarchy of C Structures in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a C language-based project. But here in the context menu, I can not find any option for viewing the type hierarchies. How to view the type hierarchy of C Structures in  VSCODE.

For example, assume I have following two C structures.

```
typedef struct {
 ....
} A;

typedef struct {
.....
 A var_a;
} A;
```

Now I want to find which structures include A as their member variable. How to do this in VSCODE?

Comment: you redefine `struct A`

Comment: There is very little point in redefining everything yourself. Besides this, VSCODE have this option for other languages.

Comment: because that language server implements that feature, it is not a feature of VSC